# perl replace curly brackets with normal brackets

Tags: perl, replace

I need to write a script which looks at a file and replaces any curly brackets with normal brackets. so far I have:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open(INFILE,"<rscore") || die "Couldn't open rscore for reading!\n";
open(OUTFILE,">rscore.new") || die "Couldn't open rscore.new for writing!\n";
while(<INFILE>){
  $_ =~ s/{/(/gi; #g for every occurrence, i for case-insensitive
  print OUTFILE $_;
}
close INFILE;
close OUTFILE;
rename("rscore.new","rscore") || die "Couldn't rename the new file!\n";
```

and getting the following error:

```
syntax error near line 10 near insensitive print.
```

This is probably something stupid. Also if there is a more efficient way of doing this (which i'm sure there is) i'd be open to suggestions.

Comment: you need to escape your opening parenthesis with \.

Comment: Your syntax error seems to be caused by a line-break in your comment, causing "case-insensitive" to be split and "insensitive" ending up on an uncommented line above the `print`. This is probably due to using an editor which is not suitable for writing code.

Comment: Lone Shepherd: no, you don't; ( isn't anything special in the substitution part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a perl one-liner.

```
$ perl -lpe 'tr |{}|()|' <infile >outfile
```

Comment: > was unexpected at this time?

Comment: @brucezepplin: The `$` is the shell prompt and is meant to indicate that this is a command-line for a sh-like shell (bash et. al.). If you are on windows without a bash clone, then you will probably need to replace the single quotes with double: `c:> perl -lpe "tr |{}|()|" <infile >outfile`. Again, the `c:>` is just the shell prompt, so don't type that.

Comment: `<` is redundant when using the `-p` or `-n` switches.

Comment: He may not even need a perl script for this, instead using the `tr` command directly: `tr '{}' '()' infile > outfile`

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

`$string =~ tr/{}/()/;`

Answer (score 1):

This is a perl one liner for inplace editing the file

```
perl -pi -e 's/{/(/g;s/}/)/g' your_file
```

This below will print the output on console

```
perl -p -e 's/{/(/g;s/}/)/g' your_file
```